# PowerShell: Rename files with file listing order control

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script that includes the following:

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {
$c++
$newname = "$($c)-TZ.jpg".Padleft(10,'0')
Rename-Item $_ -NewName $newname
}
```

In the past this has been run on folders with contents like:

```
001.jpg
002.jpg
...
037.jpg
```

It works fine and just inserts the -TZ

But now I come to run it on folders with contents like:

```
07.jpg
08.jpg
09.jpg
010.jpg
```

And it puts `010.jpg` first (renames it to `001-TZ.jpg`, when I want the first file, i.e. `07.jpg` to become `001-TZ.jpg`).

I assume this is because it is treating the numbers like letters when it orders the files (or I guess you could say like decimals). Can this be changed somehow so that it sees `07` as less than `010`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incrementing counter is not needed if just allowing the digits in the file name to dictate the 'new name' suffices. Save the digit portion of the file name to a variable, add that to the file object iterated as an `Add-Member` as the `-NotePropertyName` value, and then sort by its name to get the preferred sort order.

Essentially **this pads the matching value of digits with zeros to 3 characters** and *then when you sort by those values on the objects, the sort order will be correct* for your need.

If you **absolutely require the counter** and the file name digits themselves cannot be used for the new file name, then *this allows you to incorporate that back into the mix* and **will still resolve your problem—sorting the result by the "defined" property**—then the `rename-item` operation.

### PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {
    ###if ($_.Name -match "\d+"){$matches}else{$false};
    ###if ($_.Name -match "\d+"){$matches.Values}else{$false};
    $cName = if($_.Name -match "\d+"){[string]$matches.Values.PadLeft(3,"0")}else{$false};
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "cName" -NotePropertyValue $cName;
    $_ | Select *;
    } } | Sort cName | foreach {Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Padleft(10,'0'))$($_.Extension)"};
```

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3)
- [about_If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.3)