# How to monitor and move files to different directories one by one and in sequence on Windows?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, file-transfer, monitoring, move

How to monitor when files are created and then move them to different directories one by one and in sequence on Windows?

For example, I have files in `C:\Temp`

File names are random like `File545.tmp` `File281.tmp` `File351.tmp` but they are created at different times

I want to move these files one by one to specific folders in sequence like first file, the oldest one, to `C:\Temp\1\` and second file, second oldest, to `C:\Temp\2\` and so on. The destination folders are already exist.

How to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Which programming languages do you know? Why are you so poor VIP72?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What do you mean with "*monitor* and move files"? What is the "first file"? The oldest one? Are `C:\Temp\1` and `C:\Temp\2` supposed to be directories or files? If directories, do they already exist or do you want to create the directories? What if some of the directories exist and others don't?

Comment: https://krebsonsecurity.com/2021/09/15-year-old-malware-proxy-network-vip72-goes-dark/ Such a great profile picture...

Comment: Question edited for correctness and details added

Comment: Which programming languages do you know?

Comment: Since this is on Windows I think I'll need help in powershell

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Well I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558212/powershell-how-to-mointor-a-directory-and-move-files-over-to-another-folder but it doesnt have the function to move each one to different folder in sequence

Comment: Here's a starting point, but I'm sure there is already answers on SU where this is a duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1791289/powershell-rename-files-with-file-listing-order-control/1791353#1791353 I noticed some mods close posts for PowerShell that are dupes to existing answers but as "need more detail" whereas someone asks the same sort of thing for batch and close those for dupes pointing to their answers for scripts written for people in batch.... bias smh! Start there, search adding in a counter, and use `move-file`, etc.—trivial.